# C# 4.0 - Does calling a protected method on a dynamic object call TryInvokeMember()?

Tags: c#, dynamic, magic-methods

In C# 4.0, there is a new DynamicObject.

It provides a "magic method" TryInvokeMember() that gets called when trying to call a method that does not exist.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryinvokemember%28VS.100%29.aspx

What I would like to know is if TryInvokeMember() gets called when trying to call a protected method from outside the defining class.

I am contrasting the behaviour with PHP, which does call its equivalent "magic method" __call() in this situation.

Comment: Not to be a prick, but the first thing I would do in this scenario is try it and see :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write a call that would invoke a method that is not accessible (using the standard C# access rules), then the inaccessible method won't be called and the runtime will call the `TryInvokeMember` (where you can handle the call in some other way). Here is an example, so that you can try it:

```
class Test : DynamicObject {
  public void Foo() {
    Console.WriteLine("Foo called");
  }
  protected void Bar() {
    Console.WriteLine("Bar called");
  }

  public override bool TryInvokeMember
      (InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result) {
    Console.WriteLine("Calling: " + binder.Name);
    return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
  }
}
```

Now, we can create an instance of the object and try calling some of its methods:

```
dynamic d = new Test();
d.Foo(); // this will call 'Foo' directly (without calling 'TryInvokeMember')
d.Bar(); // this will call 'TryInvokeMember' and then throw exception
```

So, if you call the `base` implementation of `TryInvokeMember`, the C# dynamic binder will fail when calling an inaccessible method, but you can define your own handling of the case in `TryInvokeMember` (by setting the `result` to some value and returning `true`).

Comment: Just to clarify the issue. It throws an exception because you call a default binder. Just change "return base.TryInvoke" to something like "result = null; return true;" to avoid the exception. 
You probably didn't mean it, but now it looks like calling a protected method will always result in an exception (or is it my tech writer nit-picking?)

Comment: Tomas, it has been ages since you said you would clarify the last sentence. How long should we wait?